# Submit a form only when 'enter' key is pressed

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, razor

I have an input like this which submits a form on key-up event:

```
<input id="filter_package_byidphrase" asp-for="@Model.FilterByPackageIdPhrase" class="package_list_list_filter_controll_input" onkeyup="this.form.submit()">
```

I want the form to be submitted only when 'enter' is pressed (up). I already tried solution like this, but it didn't work:

```
 <input id="filter_package_byidphrase" asp-for="@Model.FilterByPackageIdPhrase" class="package_list_list_filter_controll_input" onkeyup="keypressHandler">

 <script type="text/javascript">
      function keypressHandler(e)
      {
           if(e.keyCode == 13) {
                 e.preventDefault();
                 $('#filterform').submit();
           }
      }
 </script>
```

Comment: You don't call the `submit` function. Use the invocation operator => `()`

Comment: @Ram I actually do use it, it was a typo in my question. But it still doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be helpful to trigger the function inside the  tag from the parent. Like this

```
<form id="myform" onsubmit="event.preventDefault()">
    <input type='text' id='input' onkeyup="keypressHandler(event)" />
</form>
<script>
    function keypressHandler(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 13)
           myform.submit();
    }
</script>
```